# Массив элементов класса в C#

Tags: c#, массивы

Хотелось бы создать массив элементов класса TreeNode. ООП знаю не так давно, поэтому возникают проблемы. Вот мой вариант

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TreeNode[] treeNode = new TreeNode[5];
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Вводите английское слово: ");
            treeNode[counter].key = Console.ReadLine(); Console.WriteLine("Вводите       перевод: ");
            treeNode[counter].value = Console.ReadLine();

            treeNode[counter].color = true;
        }
    }
```

Выдает NullReferenceExeption после первого ввода английского слова. Вот сам класс

```
class TreeNode{
public int numNode; // number of this node
public string key; // english word
public string value; // russian word
public bool color; // true = RED, false = BLACK
public int grandNode; // number of grandparent
public int uncleNode; // number of uncle
```

}

Может кто-нибудь подсказать в чем дело и как это исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не инициализируете элементы массива, добавьте в начале цикла:

```
treeNode[counter] = new TreeNode();
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное.